# Proof by induction: $F_{3n-1}$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

**Note:** For this problem, I am using the definition of Fibonacci numbers such that $F_0 = 1, F_1 = 1, F_2 = 2$, and so on.

Here's my current work.

Proof.
The proof is by induction on n.
**Basis step**: For $n = 1, F_2 = 2$. $2|2$, so the statement is true for $n = 1$.
**Induction hypothesis**: Assume that the statement is true for some positive integer $k$. That is, $F_{3k-1}$ is even, in other words, $2|F_{3k-1}$.

Now I need to show that $2|F_{3k + 2}$.

I know that $F_{3k + 2} = F_{3k + 1} + F_{3k}$, amongst other Fibonacci recurrences, but I'm not exactly sure how to get from $F_{3k-1}$ up to $F_{3k + 2}$ and prove it's even.

Comment: See http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/4-3/halton.pdf

Comment: "F3k+2=F3k+1+F3k+⋯+F0"   Where does this come from? The Fibonacci sequence is F3k+2=F3k+1+F3k.

Answer (score 1):

$F_{3k}\equiv F_{3k+1} \pmod{2}$ by the induction hypothesis.
Then, $$F_{3k+2}\equiv F_{3k}+F_{3k+1}\equiv 2F_{3k}\equiv 0 \pmod2 $$

Comment: $F_{3k-1}\equiv F_{3(k+1)-1}$

Answer (score 1):

$$F_{3(m+1)-1}=F_{3m+1}+F_{3m}=(F_{3m}+F_{3m-1})+(F_{3m-1}+F_{3m-2})$$

$$=F_{3m-1}+F_{3m-2}+2F_{3m-1}+F_{3m-2}$$

$$\implies F_{3(m+1)-1}\equiv3  F_{3m-1}\pmod2$$

So, $2\mid F_{3(m+1)-1}\iff 2|F_{3m-1}$

Answer (score 0):

In induction proofs, it is fairly often useful to *strengthen the induction hypothesis*. We will prove that for every positive integer $n$, $F_{3n-3}$ and $F_{3n-2}$ are odd, and $F_{3n-1}$ is even.

The result is true by inspection for $n=1$.

Now suppose that for a particular $k$ we have $F_{3k-3}$ and $F_{3k-2}$ odd  and $F_{3k-1}$ even. We will show that $F_{3k}$ and $F_{3k+1}$ are odd, and $F_{3k+2}$ is even.

Since by the induction hypothesis $F_{3k-2}$ is odd, and $F_{3k-1}$ is even, it follows that $F_{3k}$ is odd.

Since $F_{3k-1}$ is even and $F_{3k}$ is odd, it follows that $F_{3k+1}$ is odd.

And finally because $F_{3k}$ and $F_{3k+1}$ is odd, $F_{3k+2}$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

$F_{3k+2}=F_{3k+1}+F_{3k}$ and $F_{3k+1}=F_{3k}+F_{3k-1}$

So $F_{3k+2}=2F_{3k}+F_{3k-1}$

Since $F_{3k}$ is an integer, if $F_{3k-1}$ is even then $F_{3k+2}$ must be even.